# Javascript Code Not Looping

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Hi Everyone I been animating a sprite using only javascript & css techniques it animate but it wont do any looping. When it reach the end of the image it turns into a blank image already.

Here's my code:

```
<html>  
<head>
    <style type="text/css">         
        .container 
        { 
            width: 512px; 
            height: 512px; 
            overflow: hidden; 
        }    
    </style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>    
        document.onreadystatechange = function () 
        {
            if (document.readyState == "complete") 
            {
                setInterval(next, 100);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        var frame = 1;

        function next()
        {
            var left = 512 * frame;    
            var top = 0;
            var elementStyle = document.getElementById('image').style;

            elementStyle.position = "relative";
            elementStyle.top = '-'+top+'px';
            elementStyle.left = '-'+left+'px';

            frame++;
        }
    </script>    
</head>    
<body>    
    <div class="container">
        <img id="image" src="flame_sprite.png" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the picture I'm using to test the code:

http://www.thecave.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/flame_sprite.png

Kindly Explain to me what is wrong on my code also if someone can help me fixed it I'm very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 6 frames on your picture, you must loop on it, add  `if(frame == 6 ) frame = 0;` to restart your animation.

```
function next()
{
    if(frame == 6 ) frame = 0;

    var left = 512 * frame;

    var top = 0;

    var elementStyle = document.getElementById('image').style;

    elementStyle.position = "relative";

    elementStyle.top = '-'+top+'px';

    elementStyle.left = '-'+left+'px';

    frame++;

 }
```

Show result  : http://jsfiddle.net/59yhuk8L/

Comment: is there any way not counting the frame?

Comment: otherwise you could test the width of the picture

Comment: what you mean test the width?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0LkehL8s/  thanks to validate my answer if you find it correct

Comment: i try to run that code on my local it wont work it doesnt loop already try it.